# EOSIO Error: 3040006 from api

Tags: transactions, eosjs, api, error, apiendpoint

from this afternoon we receive the error in question from the api, without having changed anything after several months of use. Anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Error-Code 3040006's message is "Transaction Expiration Too Far"

What kind of client (cleos, eos-js, eos-sharp?) and what kind of network (EOS-mainnet, Telos, Wax?) are you using?

Default maximum transaction lifetime is 3600 seconds, therefore if expiration exceeds this maximum, you will get this error.

Here are the things I would do:

1. Check if there are there any problems with the time on the machine(s) the transaction is sent from
2. Check the transaction-expiration-field of the transaction(s).
3. If you are using a private network, check if max-transaction-lifetime is set to a different value

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The client is eos-js, the network the EOS-mainnet. We checked the server date and it's ok, and the transaction-expiration-field hasn't been changed, it's under 30 seconds

Comment: Have you tried pushing the transactions to a different node?